# ClassNotFoundException after some changes done in manifest file

Tags: android, package, manifest, classnotfoundexception

hey guys
i change the package name in manifest file so that i have a separate package for all the activities and it is giving me error classnotfoundexception when although the classes shown in log cat are present in my source folder.

i even then changed the package name to previous one. and still it is giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manifest file, if the package address of the activity contains a relative namespace address (starting with a dot) like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".addr.MainActivity"
    </activity>
```

you can get it to work by changing it to the full address like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.pkg.addr.MainActivity"
    </activity>
```

Comment: yes i have done dat also i have tried every possible permutation and combination it seems like there is another apk which is been created in data/app folder

Comment: this is the error which i get 03-31 14:56:41.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.FourSquare.activity.facebookLogin in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.FourSquare.activity-1.apk]
while i do have a class at this position

Comment: it looks like the error is coming from the app FourSquare installed on your phone, and has nothing to do with your app